# Angularjs and ionic, $state.go changing state but login page does not go away

Tags: angularjs, authentication, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic-view

I am new to angulajr and ionic. I am working on an application which requires user login.

I want to navigate to /dashboard when the user login is successful... but I am not getting that result!
When I login, the page's url changes to `/dasboard`but the `ion-nav-view` is not changed. The login page is still there. The dasboard and side menu, everything is loaded behind that login page.

I am new to this and I dont know what to do.
here are some screenshots;

[before login screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypymf.png)

[after login screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8FUD.png)

When the url changes to `/dashboard`, when I reload the page, my app works fine...

What I want is when I login, if my login is successful, login page must go away and the app should work

Please help. I am very new to AngularJS and Ionic.

**states.js**

```
cb_application.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
.state('dashboard', {url: '/dashboard',views: {'menuContent': {templateUrl: 'modules/dashboard.html',controller:'admin_dashboard'}}})
.state('configuration', {url: '/add-static-ip',views: {'menuContent': {templateUrl: 'modules/configuration.html',controller: 'admin_view_static_ip'}}})
.state('support', {url: '/support',views: {'menuContent': {templateUrl: 'modules/support.html',controller: 'admin_support'}}})
.state('services', {url: '/servers',views: {'menuContent': {templateUrl: 'modules/services.html',controller: 'admin_view_server'}}})
.state('cards', {url: '/cards',views: {'menuContent': {templateUrl: 'modules/cards.html',controller: 'admin_cards'}}})
.state('profiles', {url: '/profiles',views: {'menuContent': {templateUrl: 'modules/profiles.html',controller: 'admin_view_profiles'}}})
.state('people', {url: '/people',views: {'menuContent': {templateUrl: 'modules/people.html',controller: 'admin_people'}}})
.state('show_dealers', {url: '/people/dealers'})
.state('show_resellers', {url: '/people/resellers'})
.state('people_detail', {url: '/people/:type/:id',views: {'menuContent': {templateUrl: 'modules/people_detail.html',controller: 'people_detail'}}})
.state('invoices', {url: '/invoices',views: {'menuContent': {templateUrl: 'modules/invoices.html'}}})
/*Login state*/
.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'modules/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
})
// Go back to cb's home
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});
```

**modules/login.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" scroll="false">
<ion-content>
    <form ng-submit="login()">
        <div class="list list-inset">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="data.username">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="data.password">
            </label>
        </div>
        <button class="button button-block button-calm" type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

**login.js**

```
cb_application.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, LoginService, $ionicPopup, $state) {
$scope.data = {};

$scope.login = function() {
    LoginService.loginUser($scope.data.username, $scope.data.password).success(function(data) {
            $state.go('dashboard');
        }).error(function(data) {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Login failed!',
                template: 'Please check your credentials!'
            });
        });
    }
})
.service('LoginService', function($q) {
    return {
        loginUser: function(username, password) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var promise = deferred.promise;
            if (username == 'admin' && password == 'admin') {
                deferred.resolve('Welcome ' + username + '!');
            } else {
                deferred.reject('Wrong credentials.');
            }
            promise.success = function(fn) {
                promise.then(fn);
                return promise;
            }
            promise.error = function(fn) {
                promise.then(null, fn);
                return promise;
            }
            return promise;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: You may have not injected ui-router as a dependency to the module,

Comment: No console errors sir, and I have injected ui-router cause all the states are working and there is no error in the console also... I only cant get the login page to close, everything else is working fine...